# Generating a new div for each youtube video

Tags: html, youtube

So I have this code from youtube that displays the latest video from one user:

```html
<iframe width="300" height="200" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed?max-results=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&rel=0&listType=user_uploads&list=YOUR_USERNAME_HERE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
```

I want to generate the last 12 videos from the user and put each of them in a new div that has this code:

```html
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><!-- code here --></div>
```

How do I do that?

Comment: I've never used the api, but I would guess that you would change the `max-results` to 12 and then loop through them to write your html.

Comment: And how can I do that @ZachL ?

Comment: Well, what technologies are you using? What type of languages are you writing in?

Comment: @ZachL HTML/CSS /JS, using Bootstrap framekwork.